Manga about a main character that got betrayed and stuck in a cave for a 1000 years
I don't remember how the manga start off so bear with me. All I remember is that the main character got betrayed by his party members and they used him as bait and blew up the cave. He got stuck in the cave for at least 100 and maybe 1000 years but then emerged.
I think the main character fought a dragon when he emerged and a female character saw him. but didn't approach him.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  How did the main character survive so long?  Was there someone there who trained the main character?  Did 1000 years pass in the world outside as well, or was it basically an accelerated training exercise?

Hi, ty for replying. I think I read this 2 years ago and the main character I think had a system guiding him in the beginning but then it stop when he emerged. Yes a 1000 years pass in the outside world but honestly it could be 100 years. I think someone saw him emerged from the cave as well.

Definitely something huge like 100 or 1000 years, and not just 10? Was this in full color or black and white?

Yep black and white. and yes 100 years or a thousand. But I'll bet my money on a 100 to 300 because a little bit is coming back to me now. I think the main character fought a dragon when he emerged and a female character saw him. but didn't approach him.

Do you remember how he survived for over 100 years? Or did he not survive, and became an undead? Do you recall if he fought a giant turtle that was supposed to be near-indestructable and he blew it up after it ate him? I don't remember the name of that manga off the top of my head but it might have involved hundreds of years in a cave. If the rest of that sounds familiar I can try to find it again.

Yep sounds about right.

Found what I was thinking of; no betrayal, the cave collapses due to a fight between dragons (neither of which knew about the protagonist at all). It has the hundred years, so this is still probably it.

This is likely Tada no Kabane no Youda to Iwarete Ikusei Sou, Kizuitara Saikyou no Undead ni Natteta. There are a large number of differences but the general idea of "stuck in cave for 100 years" matches.

Zion, a solo adventurer, recklessly entered a dungeon beyond his ability. Alas, that was the last thing he did. Wandering inside a dungeon for hundreds of years, as an undead, he kept advancing into the dungeon. Slaying monster left and right until his undead body underwent ‘evolution’ many times over― ―By the time he regained his ego, he had already become the strongest undead: "No Life King." The humankind, who was made aware of the appearance of a new world-class disaster monster, felt dread as they fell into the abyss of despair.

There's no betrayal - he entered a cave by himself, without any party members, and died to regular monsters. At the same time, two dragons fought above the cave; one died and crashed into the cave and sealed it off. The protagonist became an undead and presumably absorbed power from the dead dragon. He regains consciousness many years later and is surprised to discover that extremely dangerous monsters are now incapable of hurting him.
He emerges from the cave and discovers a party of human adventurers, including a female fighter. He tries to greet them, but they misunderstand his greeting as a threat and all try to attack him. When their strongest attacks do precisely nothing, they all run away. Not quite "didn't approach him", but they certainly don't become friends.
Chapter 2 has those adventurers request help from stronger adventurers; they're also unable to damage him, but manage to throw him into the path of a gigantic tortoise that eats him. He promptly destroys it from the inside, scaring everyone that watched as the tortoise's shell is supposed to be indestructible. I suspect either this is the dragon fight.
